# Flow elements vertically according to height of Container

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

i am just trying to change the flowing of Elements vertically. just like the example below:

But by default settings, the Html elements works horizontally. like this :-

```css
#container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding: 4px;
}
#secondcolumn {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: -90px;
}
#secondcolumn > span {border:1px solid red;}
#container > span {border:1px solid blue;}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<span>1.</span>
<span>i am flowing horizantally.</span>
<span>2.</span>
<span>i am flowing horizantally.</span>
<span>3.</span>
<span>i am flowing horizantally.</span>
<span>4.</span>
<span>i am flowing horizantally.</span>
<span>5.</span>
<span>i am flowing horizantally.</span>
<span>6.</span>
<span>i am flowing horizantally.</span>
<h4>Elements have to flow like this:-</h4>
<span>1.</span>
<span>i am flowing vertically.</span>
<br>
<span>2.</span>
<span>i am flowing vertically.</span>
<br>
<span>3.</span>
<span>i am flowing vertically.</span>
<br>
<span>4.</span>
<span>i am flowing vertically.</span>
<br>
<span>5.</span>
<span>i am flowing vertically.</span>
<div id="secondcolumn">
<span>6.</span>
<span>i am flowing vertically.</span>
<br>
<span>7.</span>
<span>i am flowing vertically.</span>
<br>
<span>8.</span>
<span>i am flowing vertically.</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Arranging Elements from Top to Bottom instead of Left to Right (float: down?)

Comment: You can create columns and the add to them. Once you have necessary height, move to next column

Comment: The last sentence was repeated multiple times which made no sense. Hence removed it. If it is required, please revert the edit

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I advise you to use flex like this:

```css
#container {
    display: flex;
    flex-direction: column;
    flex-wrap: wrap;
    width: 400px;
    height: 100px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding: 4px;
}

#container > span {border:1px solid blue;}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<span>1. i am flowing horizantally.</span>
<span>2. i am flowing horizantally.</span>
<span>3. i am flowing horizantally.</span>
<span>4. i am flowing horizantally.</span>
<span>5. i am flowing horizantally.</span>
<span>6. i am flowing horizantally.</span>
<span>7. i am flowing horizantally.</span>
<span>8. i am flowing horizantally.</span>
<span>9. i am flowing horizantally.</span>
</div>
```

Comment: OP wants 2 columns side by side. So you'd need 2 flex container with 50% width each

Comment: #dsmaslov That's what i need, Thank you soo much. i'll tick your answer in 3 minutes

Comment: #rajesh i just have to add short height to get 2nd column.

Comment: @dsmaslov please tell, how can i remove space between these columns https://codepen.io/xlicodes/pen/XBKPNX

without decreasing width.

Answer (score 0):

You can try using `display: block` on span. Something like this :

You know how to keep '1.' and 'I am flowing horizontally' in same line. Just keep those in the same span.

```css
#container {
    position: absolute;
    width: 400px;
    height: 200px;
    border: 1px solid green;
    padding: 4px;
}

#container span{
    display: block;
}
#secondcolumn {
    position: absolute;
    margin-left: 200px;
    margin-top: -90px;
}
#secondcolumn > span {border:1px solid red;}
#container > span {border:1px solid blue;}
```

```html
<div id="container">
<span>1.</span>
<span>i am flowing horizantally.</span>
<span>2.</span>
<span>i am flowing horizantally.</span>
<span>3.</span>
<span>i am flowing horizantally.</span>
<span>4.</span>
<span>i am flowing horizantally.</span>
<span>5.</span>
<span>i am flowing horizantally.</span>
<span>6.</span>
<span>i am flowing horizantally.</span>
<h4>Elements have to flow like this:-</h4>
<span>1.</span>
<span>i am flowing vertically.</span>
<br>
<span>2.</span>
<span>i am flowing vertically.</span>
<br>
<span>3.</span>
<span>i am flowing vertically.</span>
<br>
<span>4.</span>
<span>i am flowing vertically.</span>
<br>
<span>5.</span>
<span>i am flowing vertically.</span>
<div id="secondcolumn">
<span>6.</span>
<span>i am flowing vertically.</span>
<br>
<span>7.</span>
<span>i am flowing vertically.</span>
<br>
<span>8.</span>
<span>i am flowing vertically.</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

It is possible to do this by css flexbox but it is not supported by old browsers.

```css
.container {
  position: absolute;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100px;
  display: flex;
  flex-direction: column;
  flex-wrap: wrap;
  border: solid 1px red;
}

.container > div {
  width: 50%;
  border: solid 1px blue;
}
```

```html
<div class="container">
<div>
<span>1.</span>
<span>i am flowing vertically.</span>
</div>
<div>
<span>2.</span>
<span>i am flowing vertically.</span>
</div>
<div>
<span>3.</span>
<span>i am flowing vertically.</span>
</div>
<div>
<span>4.</span>
<span>i am flowing vertically.</span>
</div>
<div>
<span>5.</span>
<span>i am flowing vertically.</span>
</div>
<div>
<span>6.</span>
<span>i am flowing vertically.</span>
</div>
<div>
<span>7.</span>
<span>i am flowing vertically.</span>
</div>
<div>
<span>8.</span>
<span>i am flowing vertically.</span>
</div>
</div>
```

Here is the link for supported browsers: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/css3_pr_flex-wrap.asp

Comment: @lvan Simeonoff please tell, how can i remove space between these columns https://codepen.io/xlicodes/pen/XBKPNX

without decreasing width.

Comment: You need adding this on ul element:
    align-content: flex-start;